# Sending and receiving unequal blocks via OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I am trying to send data via OpenSSL.

When I do

SSL_write(2777 bytes); 
SSL_write(2777 bytes);

And on the other side:

SSL_read(2777 bytes); 
SSL_read(2777 bytes);

Everything works OK.

However, if the receiving side is modified to read data in smaller chunks (257 bytes) it will read first 2777 bytes OK. Past that, I get junk data.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to frame a message on the wire. Don't read more bytes than are part of a message or serialized object. Out of curiosity... if you send 2777  bytes, then how do you reason you can read more than 2777 bytes at the receiver? Where do you think the extra bytes come from?

Comment: SSL is supposed to provide a bytestream, not a stream of messages, correct? If so, it should be perfectly OK to send 2777 bytes, then another 2777 bytes and read the data on the other side by reading chunks of 257 bytes.

Comment: @MartinSustrik, does SSL_read return an error with the second read? Please note that SSL is record oriented protocol. But SSL_read without errors indicate that at least one SSL record successfully decoded.